# Приватное наследование

Tags: c++, ооп

Я правильно понимаю, что у нас при приватном наследовании, уровень приватных членов производного класса делится как бы на приватный и на приватный приватный. То есть при приватном наследовании, поле базового класса уходит в разряд приватных полей производного, если оно было в публичных у базового - к такому полю в производном классе мы можем обратиться через публичный метод производного. Поле базового класса уходит в разряд приватных приватных производного, если оно было приватным в базовом - к такому полю мы можем обратиться так: публичные методы производного -> приватные методы от унаследованные от базового -> (на приватном приватном уровне) переменная унаследованная от базового ( которая там была приватной)?

Соответственно если создать иерархию N классов одним приватным наследованием, то можно иметь N подуровней приватного уровня в крайнем потомке))

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    public:
    A(){ch = 'A'; a = 100;}
    void showA(){
        cout << ch << endl;
    }
    int a;
    private:
    void showC(){
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }
    char ch;
};
class B : A {
    public:
    void showB(){
        showA();
    }
    void showZ(){
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    //    void showCh(){
    //        cout << ch << emdl;
    //    }
    private:
};
int main()
{
    B obj;
    obj.showZ();
    obj.showB();  // output: A
    //obj.showCh(); // error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может тут и можно выстроить какую-то хитрую многоуровневую терминологию, но смысла я навскидку не вижу. Пока что всем хватало лишь трех уровней: private, protected и public и того, как они преобразовываются друг в друга при private, protected и public наследовании.

Comment: вообше о чем речь не понел

Comment: Но к private полю базового класса в любом случаи не имеет доступ производный класс

Comment: https://atomicobject.com/uploads/archive/images/2_2_graphic_4.gif